# App access blocked due to App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP and done almost everything

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, app-transport-security

I am trying to login on my `iOS` App via Facebook using `6.4 SDK version`, and I am constantly getting this error although I have done almost everything the Facebook developers page and SO here, recommends! Please help.
I get this message:

**Error**

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Here attached is a snapshot of my `Info.Plist` Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this also  Allows Arbitrary Loads

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have added only this much in my info.plist

Can you try this

[image]

Comment: Wait let me try this. Will get back to you.

Comment: Ok, so that worked. Now Im not getting that but XPC Connection Interrupted. However, can you please explain why Facebook then recommends all those keys and values when configuring Info.plist ? This is in conflict to their login flow.

Comment: It happened there are some keys missing in your plist .

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/518113611684599/?platform=ios configure ur plist and then modify arbitrary allows. It will work.

Comment: I already went through your recommended link and was working fine earlier but sure I see your answer is appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your info.plist file of your project with any editor of your preference, then add this code at the end of the file before the last

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```